# Can I fly domestically within the US as a Canadian citizen?

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, regulations, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen, and will be entering the US by train. I then plan on taking two flights within the US, and going back to Canada by train. This is a bit unusual, in that people usually fly to and from different countries, so I am wondering, will I be able to do this without any problems? Are there any restrictions? Do I need to do something in particular when ordering my tickets? I have a valid Canadian passport.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need a form of ID, but legally once you're in the country you can take any form of transport that a US citizen can.  Plane, train, bus, ferry or automobile - your citizenship will have no bearing on whether you can use it.

Answer (score 8):

No problems whatsoever. Foreigners take US domestic flights quite often. Just show your passport to the TSA when passing the security lane, and even your Canadian driving license might be enough - check on the TSA site.

Comment: Canadian Drivers licenses ARE acceptable identification for flights in the US.  Officially other countries licenses are NOT acceptable, however I've successfully (accidentally!) used my Australian Drivers License several times - it always gets a comment, but I've always been let through when using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! I will have my passport with me anyways of course.